# How to print a multi-valued parameter in an RDL?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm creating a report in VS2013 and this report has parameters. One of the parameters "@IncludeCountries" "allows multiple values".

How can I print all of the values that are selected in @IncludeCountries in my report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This author has a very detailed explanation on how to do it. Its very good practice to always show the report user what parameters were chosen for a given report:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2844/working-with-multiselect-parameters-for-ssrs-reports/